# Unicode Checkmark defaulting to black on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, unicode

I'm having issues with unicode checkmarks on mobile. On desktop the inherit the color that's specified in the CSS but on mobile it only shows up as black.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is how I am changing the color that works on desktop:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1"></label>

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
content: '✔';
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1.6em;
color: red;
}
```

JS Fiddle example that you can checkout on mobile too: http://jsfiddle.net/wqf6fmrv/14/

Comment: I don't know if it's the reason, but there is one too many `}` at the end of your CSS. Also, `label:after` should actually be `label::after`. The former is old syntax which is still supported by most browsers, but maybe this particular mobile browser doesn't. -edit- Nevermind, that's silly. Then the check wouldn't appear either.

Comment: @GolezTrol Pretty sure that neither of those things have anything to do with it. This seems like a unicode rendering problem.

Comment: On my mobile, the check mark is red.

Comment: @GolezTrol Good catch. I based my fiddle off a preexisting one so I didnt pay too much attention to syntax but the colour is showing as black in every example I've seen online too.

Comment: @MrLister Can you give me a little more info on that? (Phone type, browser, etc) I've tested it on an iPhone 4s, 5 and 6 and all are giving different results.

Comment: @kroberrtsonn On an Android 4.1.2, the check is red in both the "Browser" and in Firefox. And another with Android 4.4.2 where I've only got "Browser" installed, also gets a red checkmark. I don't have an iPhone to test on, sorry!

Comment: @MrLister Thanks! Yeah no worries. I have 4 different iPhones sitting in front of me but that's not getting me anywhere. Seems to work on the Android phones I've tested as well.

Comment: Some mobile platforms may render the checkmark as an emoji, and these have fixed colours.